# is there a way to return a selector to an element? is it $(this) or some other method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a lot of stuff moving about, and i was going to make a hashmap in javascript to allow me to remember certain things, one of which is objects recently touched.  With that said, i was curious if i could create a key->value or array which hold the selector of the item clicked.

I wasnt sure if it was something like:

```
var item = new Array();
$("div.item").click(function(){
   item.push($(this));
});
```

Then each item that is clicked is added to the array and i could do something like:

```
$(item).each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your final goal is, but yes you could do it like that. Though I think you have to create an array of DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: What is the question? An element doesn't have a selector as it can match infinite selectors.

Comment: @FelixKling: No, jQuery objects will work fine. This is valid code from what I can see.

Comment: @Elliot: I sometimes had problems with jQuery working on a set of jQuery objects, but it worked fine with DOM elements. Maybe it was an other function though. The documentation normally states what is expected. For example, for `jQuery` it says: *"An array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery object"*. **edit:** A set of jQuery objects **does not** work: http://jsfiddle.net/f7CsN/

Comment: `$($($($(this))))` and so on is fine, it's just redundant. And `.each` shouldn't care about what's in the jQuery object. Most of the methods are sensitive to this, but not `.each`.

Comment: Why not adding a class like `selected` to the elements and then modifying them?

Comment: i wanted to store a reference/pointer to the item being moved.  Adding a selected class might be a way to do it.  I am trying to arrange code and then  move a bunch of elements at once.   I guess the difference really is doing an array of objects or a selector... depends if i want to be more of a programmer or jquery guru.heh

Comment: @Esailija: You are right, `.each` will work in this case, but still `$(item)` won't be a proper jQuery object to work with, see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @FelixKling you are using `.css`, not `.each` see http://jsfiddle.net/f7CsN/1/. There is a lot of redudant jQuery wrapping going on but it still works with `.each` :P

Comment: @Esailija: I know, that's why I said `.each` works ;) but it is a bit deceptive.

Comment: ah I see, I am getting lost here... and I still don't know [what the question is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904679/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-selector-to-an-element-is-it-this-or-some-other-m#comment15847663_11904679)

Comment: The more you know. :)  http://cdn1.hark.com/images/000/006/085/6085/original.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an array, you can use a jQuery object:

```
var $items = $();
$("div.item").click(function () {
   $items = $items.add(this);
});
$items.css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5qaT/

Comment: i think i like this one the most, and i was looking at the fiddle.  Storing it in the jquery object will NOT move it around the DOM but instead just store a reference to it, so that way when i call $items, it will call everything in the object?

Answer (score 2):

Make an empty jQuery collection and add to it.

```
var items = $([]);
$("div.item").click(function(){
   var elem = $(this);
   items = items.add(elem);
});
```

Comment: is there a difference when declaring a jquery collection verses a jquery object you refer to?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Whether you collect the elements in an array and do `$([element, element, ....])` or instead `$().add(element).add(element)....` does not make a difference. Whatever makes more sense to you.

Comment: @FelixKling doesn't `.add` use pushStack. It keeps creating new jQuery objects for each `.add` so it is much more expensive that way. Not that it matters, just saying.

Comment: @Esailija: Good point, did not think about that... lets say for working with it at the end, it does not make a big difference.

Answer (score -3):

You want to pass the event as an argument in your eventhandler function. Like so:

```
$("div.item").click(function(e){...
    e.whateverYouWantToDoWithIt;
```

The event is a javascript object, not jquery. You can google javascript event methods, attributes, etc. to see what you can do with it.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I read your question kind of fast. If you want to store the actual DOM object (the div) in the array, then yes, you would use the $(this) selector.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, re: how to remember clicked elements. Moreover, in the case of jQuery, the passed event object is a jQuery object - it's not the same as the native event object. This is available under `evt.originalEvent`